# SQL query to Calculate allocation / netting

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is my source data,

```
Group | Item | Capacity
-----------------------
1     | A    | 100 
1     | B    | 80 
1     | C    | 20 
2     | A    | 90 
2     | B    | 40 
2     | C    | 20
```

The above data shows the capacity to consume "something" for each item.
Now suppose I have maximum 100 allocated to each group. I want to distribute this "100" to each group upto the item's maximum capacity. So my desired output is like this:

```
Group | Item | Capacity | consumption
-------------------------------------
1     | A    | 100      | 100
1     | B    | 80       | 0
1     | C    | 20       | 0
2     | A    | 90       | 90
2     | B    | 40       | 10
2     | C    | 20       | 0
```

My question is how do I do it in a single SQL query (preferably avoiding any subquery construct). Please note, number of items in each group is not fixed.

I was trying `LAG()` with running `SUM()`, but could not quite produce the desired output...

```
select 
group, item, capacity,
sum (capacity) over (partition by group order by item range between UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) run_tot,
from table_name
```

Comment: Why prefer to avoid a subquery, or multiple queries? Why not prefer the most performant solution, accepting whatever implementation that requires?   In essence, is this a real problem or a code golf question?

Comment: @JonathanVanMatre Whether or not subquery is "performant" that is debatable.. but just to explain you the reason - This query is not going to get executed directly against database. This query will be used as an "SQL Override" inside a Financial reporting tool (called Axiom ControllerView) in a sort of SQL Injection pattern where sub-query construct will not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without a subquery using just the analytic SUM function:

```
SQL> create table mytable (group_id,item,capacity)
  2  as
  3  select 1, 'A' , 100 from dual union all
  4  select 1, 'B' ,  80 from dual union all
  5  select 1, 'C' ,  20 from dual union all
  6  select 2, 'A' ,  90 from dual union all
  7  select 2, 'B' ,  40 from dual union all
  8  select 2, 'C' ,  20 from dual
  9  /

Table created.

SQL> select group_id
  2       , item
  3       , capacity
  4       , case
  5         when sum(capacity) over (partition by group_id order by item) > 100 then 100
  6         else sum(capacity) over (partition by group_id order by item)
  7         end -
  8         case
  9         when nvl(sum(capacity) over (partition by group_id order by item rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding),0) > 100 then 100
 10         else nvl(sum(capacity) over (partition by group_id order by item rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding),0)
 11         end consumption
 12    from mytable
 13  /

  GROUP_ID I   CAPACITY CONSUMPTION
---------- - ---------- -----------
         1 A        100         100
         1 B         80           0
         1 C         20           0
         2 A         90          90
         2 B         40          10
         2 C         20           0

6 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using recursive subquery factoring.  This clearly ignores your preference to avoid subqueries, but doing this in one pass might be impossible.

Probably the only way to do this in one pass is to use [MODEL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/sqlmodel.htm#DWHSG022), which I'm not allowed to code after midnight.  Maybe someone waking up in Europe can figure it out.

```
with ranked_items as
(
    --Rank the items.  row_number() should also randomly break ties.
    select group_id, item, capacity,
        row_number() over (partition by group_id order by item) consumer_rank
    from consumption
),
consumer(group_id, item, consumer_rank, capacity, consumption, left_over) as
(
    --Get the first item and distribute as much of the 100 as possible.  
    select
        group_id,
        item,
        consumer_rank,
        capacity,
        least(100, capacity) consumption,
        100 - least(100, capacity) left_over
    from ranked_items
    where consumer_rank = 1
    union all
    --Find the next row by the GROUP_ID and the artificial CONSUMER_ORDER_ID.
    --Distribute as much left-over from previous consumption as possible.
    select
        ranked_items.group_id,
        ranked_items.item,
        ranked_items.consumer_rank,
        ranked_items.capacity,
        least(left_over, ranked_items.capacity) consumption,
        left_over - least(left_over, ranked_items.capacity) left_over
    from ranked_items
    join consumer
        on ranked_items.group_id = consumer.group_id
        and ranked_items.consumer_rank = consumer.consumer_rank + 1
)
select group_id, item, capacity, consumption
from consumer
order by group_id, item;
```

Sample data:

```
create table consumption(group_id number, item varchar2(1), capacity number);

insert into consumption
select 1, 'A' , 100 from dual union all
select 1, 'B' ,  80 from dual union all
select 1, 'C' ,  20 from dual union all
select 2, 'A' ,  90 from dual union all
select 2, 'B' ,  40 from dual union all
select 2, 'C' ,  20 from dual;
commit;
```

Comment: +1 for "...MODEL, which I'm not allowed to code after midnight" :))

Answer (score 1):

Does this work as expected?

```
WITH t AS
    (SELECT GROUP_ID, item, capacity,
    SUM(capacity) OVER (PARTITION BY GROUP_ID ORDER BY item RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) sum_run,
    GREATEST(100-SUM(capacity) OVER (PARTITION BY GROUP_ID ORDER BY item RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW), 0) AS remain
    FROM table_name)
SELECT t.*,
    LEAST(sum_run,lag(remain, 1, 100) OVER (PARTITION BY GROUP_ID ORDER BY item)) AS run_tot
FROM t
```

Comment: You wrote "Now suppose I have maximum 100 allocated to each group." Do you have any column or rule what the over all capacity is per group? This you can replace with hard coded 100. Your given example data does not tell this value.

Comment: @Wernfried - yes, it does work! I won't mind that hard-coding as for my requirement, this number is pretty much constant. But I am still accepting Rob's answer due to it's conciseness.

Answer (score 0):

```
  select  group_id,item,capacity,(case when rn=1 then capacity else 0 end) consumption
  from 
  (select group_id,item,capacity,
  row_number() over (partition by group_id order by capacity desc) rn from mytable)
```

Comment: Close but does not match with the expected answer (check for the row Group 2, Item B)